# ¿Por qué el redux store de angular se limpia completamente dejando las variables en su estado inicial al recargar la pagina en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, redux, dev-tools

Digamos que a través de la extensión Redux DevTools tengo este store en algún punto de mi aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero mantener mi estado global mientras navego los componentes (eso esta ok), digamos que yo recargo mi aplicación desde mi home principal, ahora cuando lo hago, el store se limpia y vuelve a su estado inicial a excepción de mi currentUser que lo seteo siempre en donde sea que me encuentre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Este comportamiento de redux es el esperado? ¿o hay alguna forma de mantener mi store a pesar de recargar el navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El estado es volátil, es un objeto que se almacena en memoria, pero al momento de cerrar el navegador o refrescar todo es borrado.

Es el comportamiento normal de Redux. Si quisiera mantener el estado podrías intentarlo con alguna librería, va a depender con la que estas usando.

La realidad es que mantener el estado no es algo común mi recomendación es que en cada carga vuelvas a llamar los APIs para llegar el estado.